# structured binding of member variables

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

In visual studio 2017, after turning on `/std:c++17`, I can do

```
auto [d1, d2] = func_return_tuple();
```

, where `func_return_tuple()` returns a tuple of two double value.

However, if class A has two member variable `d1_` and `d2_`, I can't do

```
A a;
auto [a.d1_, a.d2_] = func_return_tuple();
```

Is there a way out?

Of course,

```
std::tie(a.d1_, a.d2_) = func_return_tuple();
```

always works.

Comment: No the first is not possible, since you define the variables *twice*. And for the second variant you need to use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). [Structured binding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) isn't for general assignment, it's for variable definition and initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way out?

Basically, no. Structured bindings is only about decomposing an object into constituent elements. It always introduces *n* new names - one for each element. You cannot assign through a structured binding, nor can you use it to rebind existing names, or anything like that.

Your option is basically:

```
std::tie(a.d1_, a.d2_) = func_return_tuple();
```

---

Or, assuming `A` is an aggregate containing those two members, something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct list_init_t {
    template <typename... Args>
    T operator()(Args&&... args) const {
        return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr list_init_t<T> list_init;
```

Using it as:

```
a = std::apply(list_init<A>, func_return_tuple());
```